# what do free variable and leading variables mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

What do the leading variables and free variables in a matrix mean? I have the system below and am trying to understand which are which. I searched a lot for this, please help me ! $$w + x + y + z = 6 \qquad w + y + z = 4 \qquad w + y = 2$$

Answer (score 21):

The terms "leading variable" and "free variable" are usually defined for the matrix representing a system, and only when the matrix is in row-echelon form.

The augmented matrix for your system is
$$
\left( \begin{array}{c c c c|c}
1&1&1&1&6\\ 1&0&1&1&4\\ 1&0&1&0&2\\
\end{array}\right)
$$
Notice that each column corresponds to a variable.

Do you know how to use elementary row operations to bring this matrix to row-echelon form?

In row-echelon form, the first non-zero entry in each row (if there is one) is a $1$, and the column it is in corresponds to a leading variable; the columns that don't have that kind of $1$ correspond to the free variables. Essentially, columns that don't have a leading variable, have a free variable.

So for example if a row-echelon form is given by
$$
\left( \begin{array}{c c c c c|c}
1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 0&0&1&7&8&9\\ 0&0&0&1&\pi&\sqrt2\\
\end{array}\right)
$$ then the 1st, 3rd, and 4th variables are leading variables while the 2nd and 5th variables are free variables.

Comment: Thats good when thought of in the context of matrix representation. But what they mean in (homogeneous/nonhomogeneous) linear systems context: Is it just that **the leading variables are bound/constrained by the given equations and free variables are parametric/not bound by the  equations**? Or are there more alternative interpretations / significance / facts / observations associated with it in the context of linear system?

Comment: @awe, that would depend on how the systems are written. If they are written as, say, $a=3b-7d+11,c=12d+44, e=92$, then you can say $a,c,e$ are leading and $b,d$ are free. But if they are written $w+x+y+z=6,w+y+z=4,w+y=2$ then there is no sensible way to distinguish some of the variables as leading and others as free. The distinction only arises during the process of solving the system.

Comment: `the first non-zero entry in each row (if there is one) is a 1` This condition is not really needed for echelon form. It does does not have to be 1 and it is still echelon form.

Comment: It only needs to be nonzero.

Answer (score 3):

If a set of linear equations can be expressed as let's say

a = 3x + 4y + 5z - 12

b = 2x + 8y + z - 11

c = 9x + 7y -z - 15

where

1. The left hand variables don't appear on the right side and vice versa.
2. On the left side, there is only one variable.

Then,

1. x, y and z can take values of any combination and are called free variables.
2. a, b and c are dependent on the above free variables (x, y and z) and cannot be any combination. a, b and c are called pivot or leading variables.

One more thing, depending upon how we form the above equations the pivot and free variable might be changed. For ex.,

a = x + y + z ==> a is pivot =>  x, y, z are free variables.

The same equation can be expressed as

x = a - y - z ==> x is pivot =>  a, y, z are free variables.

I thought of explaining the free/leading variables in a non-matrix way, since the original query was in a non-matrix way. Thanks to [Gilbert Strang](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/videos.shtml) for getting me again started with Linear Algebra.