# defining a free variable

Tags: linear-algebra

Now I know that x3 is the free variable in the below case:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -5 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
        0& 0& 0&0
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
**Note that the last column of the matrix column is the augmented column**

A theorem in linear algebra state: "**If there are more variables than equation, then there is a non trivial solution(in fact infinitely many).**"

But, I'm unable to determine in the following case:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
        0& 1& 2&0
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

For a free variable it has to be the case that: x3 = 0, isn't it? but in the above case, the equations become:

x1-x3 = 0
x2+x3 = 0

Is there a free variable here? IF so how and which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_3$ is a free variable.

Let $x_3=t$, can you express $x_1=t$ and $x_2=-2t$. You get to freely choose $x_3$ and it determine $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Remark:

$x_2+x_3=0$ should be $x_2+2x_3=0$.

Comment: There's now third row so there's also no pivot,but there's no third row. What does this mean?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the term "free variable". I can freely choose `x1` and it determine `x2` and `x3`. Why should `x3`be "more free" than the other variables?

Comment: @4386427 ,I think it's because, the value of x3 doesn't effect the value of the system

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/721071/306553) to what is a free variable.

Comment: @mathmaniage i see two rows, the first two columns are pivot columns because of the position of leadign $1$'s.

Comment: @MorganRodgers and Siong Thye Goh. Thanks for the explanation. I probably learned about this some years ago but I don't recall that term anymore. Still I'm a bit puzzled about this. If I swap column 2 and 3 then `x2` would become the free variable. Or?

Comment: in that case... it is not in RREF form right?