# Why are all variables in $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}t\\ s\end{pmatrix}:t,s\in\Bbb R\right\}$ considered "free"?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I am unsure what "free" and "leading" are supposed to mean in the context of the following problem.

We have the following set:

$$\left\{ \left( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} t \\ s \end{matrix} \right): t,s \in \Bbb R \right\}$$

They are asking how many free variables and leading variables are there.  **And it turns out that all the variables are "free"!**

As far as I understood, $t$ and $s$ are supposed to be free (can take any $\Bbb R$ value) and $x$ and $y$ are dependent on $s$ and $t$, so that they are leading if "leading" is supposed to be the opposite of "free".

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720971/what-do-free-variable-and-leading-variables-mean

Comment: @Pixel from what I understood there, not all the variables in this system are free. I'm confused.

Comment: the meaning of "free" is overloaded. I also had to think twice. x and y are free in the linear algebra sense (see linked question), while s and t are free variables in the sense of set builder notation.

Comment: none would ever use this notation anyway as it suffices to write $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} s \\ t \end{pmatrix} : s,t\in\mathbb R\right\}$ (or simply write $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: My initial thoughts were to represent the system as $[1, 0; 0, 1; s, t]$ where the pairs separated by ; are columns. In that case the linked question would say that the two variables $x$ and $y$ are leading variables. I'm confused too.

Comment: There does not seem to be a reference for "leading variable" in set theory. Leading and free variable terms appear in matrix row echelon reduction. See pg 6. https://www.stats.otago.ac.nz/webdata/resources/math160/2020_S1_Algebra_Slides_and_Scans/3_EchelonForm.pdf?m=1583968013

Comment: There are references to free and bound variables in set theory. Where is the problem from?

Comment: @User, can you give me few elements of the set: $\left\{ \left( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} t \\ s \end{matrix} \right): t,s \in \Bbb R \right\}$. What are the elements of this set? Equations or what? How you understand this set?

Comment: @jorlinski I would understand it as $\mathbb R^2$. That's part of why I'm confused tbh

Comment: @arthur I'll try to find out which textbook this is from

Comment: @User Ok. But it would be wery strange if this set is just $\mathbb R^2$. I've posted an answer before read your comment. Sorry for that, but I still don't sure that is just $\mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 1):

I asume, that $$\left\{ \left( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} t \\ s \end{matrix} \right): t,s \in \Bbb R \right\}$$ is a set (or a system) of equations $x=t_{\alpha_1}, y=s_{\alpha_1}, x=t_{\alpha_2}, y=s_{\alpha_2},\dots$ (analogously as a set e.g. $\left\{nx^2 + n = 1: n\in\{2,7\}\right\}$ is a system of two equations: $2x^2+2=1$ and $7x^2 + 7 = 1$).

Then we can write:
$$ \begin{cases}1\cdot x + 0\cdot y  =t_{\alpha_1}\\
0\cdot x + 1\cdot y =s_{\alpha_1}\\
0\cdot x + 0\cdot y =t_{\alpha_2} - t_{\alpha_1}\\
0\cdot x + 0\cdot y =s_{\alpha_2} - s_{\alpha_1}\\
\vdots
\end{cases}
$$
for $\alpha_j\in\mathbb R$. So this means that $x$ and $y$ are leading variable and the rest is free (becouse are not leading - acording to pg. 6. https://www.stats.otago.ac.nz/webdata/resources/math160/2020_S1_Algebra_Slides_and_Scans/3_EchelonForm.pdf?m=1583968013), but there is no free variables in this case (no more variavbles than $x$ and $y$).