# Pivoting: Simplex Algorithm choosing a pivot column for the second time

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, simplex-method

I found online [a set of notes](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Ejack/2010-01-MA162/2010-02-25-MA162Lab.pdf) from a university.
I am studying an example of the Simplex algorithm and I am somewhat confused:

- We defined the pivot column to be the leftmost column with a negative operator in the last row
  [image]
- So in the first run of the algorithm we have:
  [image]

**Now what I don't get is what's coming next**:
[image]

***Question:*** **$x, v, w$ are exactly the ones having non-negative values in the last row**, so how come they become pivot columns?
Isn't the other way around ? $y, z$ are possible pivot columns, aren't they?

Comment: The author is using "has pivots" to refer to columns corresponding to the current basic variables, not the columns corresponding to variables that can enter the basis.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by [Brian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6310/brian-borchers), the author of this textbook is denoting the basic variable columns as "pivot columns", and the non-basic variable columns as "free variables". The terminology is confusing, however it's probably more rooted from the traditional terms used [in Linear Algebra](https://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/hudelson/free.html#:%7E:text=A%20variable%20is%20a%20basic,augmented%20matrix%20to%20echelon%20form.&text=pivot%20column%2C%20so%20x3%20is%20a%20free%20variable.) than from most modern Linear-Programming terminology.

Here are more examples of the terminology the author is using to help provide clarity:

- [what do free variable and leading variables mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/721071/1098096)
- [Row Reduction and Echelon Forms (PDF, Page 8)](https://www.unf.edu/%7Ebeyza.aslan/DavidLay/lecture_notes/c01/sec1_2an.pdf)
- [Basic Variables, Free Variables, and Parameters (PDF)](https://mathsci2.appstate.edu/%7Ewmcb/Class/2240/ClassNotes144/Basic%20Variables%20and%20Free%20Variables.pdf)

Thus, the next pivoting column, using the author's definition of pivoting, would be the $y$ "free" variable as it is the left-most negative column.

Comment: This feels similar to Bland's Rule (picking the lowest, acceptable subscript to pivot), thus I wonder if the author is setting up the next chapter/content to be that or something similar - or if it is easier to teach Simplex this way to start out